# Solving second order SDE with Gaussian white noise for first time derivative in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, stochastic

I'm having trouble solving a second order differential equation with Gaussian white noise. The equation I'm solving follows the form:

$$Ax'' + Bx' + \sin(x) = i + i_{n}$$

where $i_{n}$ is the Gaussian white noise, and $i$ is a constant source. I'm ultimately interested in $x'$, not $x$. Without the Gaussian source, I've been able to simply use an ODE solver like `ode15s` or `ode45`. However, with the random source, I don't know how to use an SDE solver to get $x'$. Can anyone with experience in solving SDEs in MATLAB lend some advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "a constant source"? Is $i$ just a constant parameter or is it noise with a uniform distribution? Or is the right-hand side an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck_process)?

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to solve your SDE is with an [Euler-Maruyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) scheme. This is a simple and effective method for additive noise, i.e., the diffusion/noise term is not a function of the state, as appears to be the case for your example. Here is some Matlab code to solve your system:

```
n = 2;        % Order of system
t0 = 0;       % Initial time
dt = 1e-3;    % Fixed time step
tf = 1;       % Final time
t = t0:dt:tf; % Time vector
tlen = length(t);

A = 1;
B = 1;
c = 1;
f = @(t,x)[x(2);(-B*x(2)-sin(x(1))+c)/A]; % Drift function
ep = 1e-1;                                % Size of additive noise
g = @(t,x)[0;ep];                         % Diffusion function

x = zeros(lt,n); % Allocate output
x0 = [1;1];
x(1,:) = x0;     % Set initial condition

seed = 1;  % Seed value
rng(seed); % Always seed random number generator

% Euler-Maruyama
for i = 1:tlen-1
    x(i+1,:) = x(i,:).' + f(t(i),x(i,:))*dt + g(t(i),x(i,:)).*randn(n,1)*sqrt(dt);
end

figure;
plot(t,x);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('State');
legend('x(t)','xdot(t)')
```

This is not an adaptive method like `ode45`, so you need to ensure that your integration step size, `dt`, is sufficiently small. There are many ways to optimize the above code and make it less general (e.g., simplify anonymous functions, pre-calculate normal variates, etc.). You could also try using `sde_euler` in my [SDETools](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools) Matlab toolbox on Github, which has many options akin to those in the ODE suite. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/745513/80812) on Math.SE.

For methods specialized to second-order SDEs like yours, you could check out [this paper](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~grant/BLL.pdf) (PDF) by Burrage, et al. For an introduction to numerically solving SDEs, I recommend this paper, which includes many Matlab examples:

> Desmond J. Higham, 2001, An Algorithmic Introduction to Numerical Simulation of Stochastic Differential Equations, SIAM Rev. (Educ. Sect.), 43 525–46. http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144500378302

The URL to the Matlab files in the paper won't work; [use this one](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/algfiles.html). Also, note that random number generator seeding used in the code is now deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got the code to work, but get the same result each time I run it. I'm ultimately hoping to generate a histogram of a certain x' threshold value, and thought the white noise would allow for this variation. Is there a reason that the code would converge to the same solution every time it's run, despite the additive noise? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a random seed is specified so the [same sequence of pseudorandom variates will be produced each time](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html). This allows you to re-run and replicate your results exactly. If you want $N$ independent runs, you either need to set the seed once at the very top of your code outside of any loop that runs the simulation $N$ times, or vectorize the integration such that all $N$ simulations are calculated simultaneously, or you could re-seed using a different value for each run (slightly less efficient).